# jquery div not respnding to other javascript/jquery methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added one div inside a div using $(select).append() method but the I want it to close it on click on image so i hav added image and an another $(select).button().click( { $(select).hide() }); but on clicking the close image nothing happens....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#subCre").click(function() {
                cust = $("#customer").val();
                address = $('#address').val();
                phone = $('#phone').val();
                amt = $('#initamount').val();
                user = '<%= session.getAttribute("user").toString()%>';
                type = '<%=session.getAttribute("type").toString()%>';
                alert(cust + address + phone + amt + user + type);
                $.post("../processor/proc2.jsp",
                        {
                            customer: cust,
                            address: address,
                            phone: phone,
                            initamount: amt,
                            user: user,
                            type: type
                        },
                function(data, status) {
                    if (status === "success") {
                        if(data.length == 11) {
                            $("#SystemMessages").append('<div class="Msg draggable"><img class="close" src="../mime/close.png">Account Added</div>'); // **Here one div
                        } else {
                            $("#SystemMessages").append('<div class="errorMsg draggable"><img class="close" src="../mime/close.png">'+ data + '</div>'); //** here 2nd div
                      }
                        $("#customer").val("");
                        $('#address').val("");
                        $('#phone').val("");
                        $('#initamount').val("");
                    }
                });

            $(".close").button().click(function() {
                $(".close").parent().css("visibility", "hidden");
            });
       });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use event delegation for dynamically appended elements

```
$('#SystemMessages').on('click','.close',function(){
    $(this).parent().css("visibility", "hidden");
});
```

Event delegation `--->`  https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 2):

Since you have *dynamically added `.close` element to the existing HTML*, you need to delegate it using [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) event handler

```
 $(".close").button();
 $("#SystemMessages").on('click', ".close", function() {
                $(".close").parent().css("visibility", "hidden");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following code

```
$('.close').live('click',function(){
  $(this).parent().hide();
 });
```

It will definitely work, let me know if it worked.

`.live()` being deprecated in jQuery version 1.7 and removed in version 1.9, so you can use `.on()` method in the following manner

```
$(document).on('click','.close',function(){
  $(this).parent().hide();
 });
```